# javafx tableview detect any change upon any of rows including addition of new one

Tags: javafx, listener, tableview

because I don't really know the sollution.
Lets say i have a TableView that holds info about product: description, quantity and the price. Also have a label that shows a sum of prices (times quantity) of all products from a table. Now i want to be notified about any changes that took affect on this component like changes in existing rows or addition of a new one. Is there any listener or sth similar to achieve it?

Comment: `table.getItems().addListener(...)`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Usually you construct a TableView by passing an ObservableList to it. Something like this:
TableView myTable = new TableView<>(myObservableList);

```
ObservableList<ClassOfTheObjectsInTheList> myObservableList = FXCollections.FXCollections.observableArrayList(anyNoneObservableCollection);
TableView<ClassOfTheObjectsInTheList> myTable = new TableView<>(myObservableList);
```

You can add a ListChangeListener to any ObservableList at will by doing:

```
myObservableList.addListener(new ListChangeListener<ClassOfObjectsInTheList>(){

                @Override
                public void onChanged(javafx.collections.ListChangeListener.Change<? extends ClassOfObjectsInTheList> pChange) {
                    while(pChange.next()) {
                        // Do your changes here
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: If this was what you were searching for, would you mind voting the answer as correct so that others searching for help find it at first glance?

Comment: @omgBob: As far as I know, this methods doesn't react to internal changes of the items. It only reacts if you add and delete items. Do you have another approach for that?

Comment: @TrudleR: This depends on the item you are trying to monitor. You can implement any of the Subinterfaces of https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/value/ObservableValue.html and add a Listener to each item. This way every change of the items is detected and can be processed in any way you'd like.

Comment: @omgBob Yeah I found out that you can use "Extractors" to listen to additional properties, which will fire an event that calls "onChange" of the itemList too. :)